# Javascript function for phone number format xx-xxxxxx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, user-interface, dom-events

I need a Javascript function which  should check whether the text in textbox is a number or else throw focus on the textbox and should change to this format (xx-xxxxxx) when we type number on it like (12-123456).
I am pretty much new to Javascript.

As far I did;
I would be using `onkeypress` and on blur event here:

```
function(elem)
{
If(Number.isInteger(elem))
{
 //To check format(xx-xxxxxx)
}
 else
 {
  elem.focus()
 }
}
```

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: Google regex that will help

Comment: Regex, jQuery and jQueryValidation plug-in, just slice the string yourself and verify each segment is a number... the possibilities are endless. I agree with Taplar... What *have* you tried?

Comment: Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Use below Regex

```
^\d{2}-\d{8}$
```

Valid E.x 
22-22229999

Here 2 and 8  is no. of digits according.You can change it according to your requirement.

```
function Validate(phone)
{
 var regex="^\d{2}-\d{8}$";
 retun regexp.test(phone);
}
```

Comment: What is that test in( return regex.test)

Comment: You have to pass the phone number enter by user into Validate() method. This will  return you valid or invalid value. Based on it,You can show validation error to user.